# PHP mssql_bind passing money datatype failed

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, data-binding, pymssql

i trying to calling mssql stored procedure from PHP and failed when trying to passing money parameter. This is my code:

```
$proc = mssql_init("sp_something");

mssql_bind($proc, "@param1", $param1,  SQLINT4, false, false);
mssql_bind($proc, "@param2", $param2,  SQLINT4, false, false);
mssql_bind($proc, "@param3", $param3,  SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 5);
mssql_bind($proc, "@param4", $param4,  SQLINT4, false, false);
mssql_bind($proc, "@param5", $param5,  SQLMONEY, false, false);
mssql_bind($proc, "@param6", $param6,  SQLMONEY, false, false);
mssql_bind($proc, "@param7", $param7,  SQLVARCHAR, true);

mssql_execute($proc);

echo mssql_get_last_message();
```

and its failed and last message is :

```
Procedure or function 'sp_something' expects parameter '@param5', 
which was not supplied.
```

this is my stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_something]
@param1 smallint,
@param2 smallint,
@param3 varchar(8),
@param4 int,
@param5 money,
@param6 money,
@param7 bit OUTPUT AS

--some stored proc
```

i try exec it from sql server management studio and its SUCCESS:

```
exec sp_something 2014,5,'123456',1,12345.23,22222.33,0
```

is there any tricky way when you want to pass money datatype? cause i have another stored procedure without money parameter and it runs smooth..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i just use with `SQLVARCHAR` for money parameter and its works well

```
mssql_bind($proc, "@param5", $param5,  SQLVARCHAR, false, false);
mssql_bind($proc, "@param6", $param6,  SQLVARCHAR, false, false);
```